# Web API 2.0 Method 'ExecuteActionFilterAsync' in type does not have an implementation

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-standard

After adding a reference to .netstandard 2.0 to an existing Web API 2.0 project, the project builds but throws an exception at runtime, where a custom action filter is registered.

Method 'ExecuteActionFilterAsync' in type 'MyActionFilter' from assembly 'MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Method 'ExecuteActionFilterAsync' in type 'MyAssembly.MyActionFilter' from assembly 'MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

```
config.Filters.Add(new MyActionFilter());
```

The Action filter:

```
public class MyActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public bool AllowMultiple => false;

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was seeing this on one of our servers after we updated the Owin libraries to 4.0.  Ended up having to revert the Owin libraries to version 3.